# Way to adding emoji to textarea with keyboard, other than copy/paste

Tags: html, keyboard, textarea, copy-paste, emoji

I have noticed that you can copy/paste an emoji from elsewhere into a textarea control on a website, like this , however  you cannot just add the code for the emoji and get the relevant emoji (eg. `&#128077;` which should be a thumbs up). If you are using a keyboard you don't have access to emojis (other than through a substitute program). So what exactly is getting pasted when you copy paste the emoji, can it be replicated by a code somehow?